# Отрезок массива с заданной суммой

Tags: алгоритм

Есть массив целых чисел `a[]`. Необходимо найти самый длинный отрезок `[l,r]` для которого сумма `a[l] + a[l+1] + ... + a[r-1] + a[r]` будет равна заданному числу. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: дерево отрезков такую задача эффективно решать не будет. Могу предложить решение скользящим окном.

Comment: Дерево построено по списку (чтоб я понимал, что это такое), так что можно считать это дерево просто кривым хранилищем для связного списка (а для понимания твоего алгоритма так и вовсе для одномерного массива), и соответствующим образом обрабатывать.

Answer (score 4):

Предполагаю, что в массиве только положительные числа. Конечно можно и с отрицательными сделать аналогичную идею, но реализация значительно сложнее.

Эта задача решается с помощью скользящего окна. Общая идея - если у нас есть отрезок, сумма на котором меньше нужной, то убрав 1 элемент она по прежнему будет меньше нужной.

Используем это примерно в таком коде (псевдо С++):

```
@input vector<unsigned int> list, int K
@return {L,R}
int sum =0;
unsigend int l = 0, r = 0;
pair res = {-1,-1}
while (true){
       if (r == list.size)
          return res;
       if (sum > K)
           sum -= list[l++];
       if (sum < K) 
           sum += list[r++];
       if (sum == K)
          if (res.second - res.first < r - l + 1)
              res = {l,r+1};    
}
```

Корректность:

Конечность: Мы каждую итерацию цикла сдвигаем либо `l` либо `r` указатель, `l` всегда не больше чем `r`. Поэтому цикл сделает не более `2*size` операций.

Правильность: Если у нас сумма на отрезке меньше нужного, то добирать можно только справа (и мы обязаны это делать). Аналогично если меньше то мы обязаны убирать левый элемент. Если у нас сумма стала больше, то добавляя другие элементы справа мы её меньше не сделаем, аналогично если сумма меньше то удалять дальше смысла нет.

Остальное доказывается тривиально.

P.S. во многих алгоритмах правую границу отрезка удобнее не включать в сам отрезок. Т.е. использовать полуинтервал `[a,b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно искать через полусуммы и их разницу:

```java
        int findingSum = 11;
        List<Integer> data = List.of(10, -5, 2, 3, -4, 5, 6, 8, -2);
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            sum += data.get(i);
            map.put(sum, i);
        }

        if (map.containsKey(findingSum)) {
            System.out.println(0 + "," + map.get(findingSum));
            return;
        }
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
            int halfSum = e.getKey();
            int d = findingSum + halfSum;
            // просматриваем только вправо ->
            if (map.containsKey(d) && map.get(d) > e.getValue()) {
                Integer right = map.get(d);
                int left = e.getValue() + 1; // берем следующий элемент
                System.out.println(left + "," + right);
                return;
            }
        }
```